# Unable to encode String for URL in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I used to develop iOS Apps using Objective-C. Now I have recently migrated to Swift. In my app, I have a button that opens MS Outlook App with the pre-filled Subject and Body.

I did a similar App in Objective-C and used the below code to Encode my String for URL.

```
NSString *emailSubject = @"Test Subject";
NSString *encodedSubject = [emailSubject stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Now I am unable to do the same in Swift 3. Below is the code that I tried.

```
var subjectText: String = "Test Subject"

var encodedSubject = subjectText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

var stringURL: String = "ms-outlook://compose?subject=" + subjectText + "&body=TestingEmailNow"
// Convert the string to a URL.
var url = URL(string: stringURL)

// Open the app that responds to the URL scheme (should be Outlook).
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

The error that I am getting is below.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-06-07 04:29:35.158030+0400 My App[1286:405793] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know that this error is coming due to the space in my Subject. I can say this because if I remove the space, I don't even have to encode it. It works directly. What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: The Swift code you posted cannot fail with this error. Can you show us the line where it actually fails?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted full Button Action Code. When I try the App with "TestSubject", it works. But fails with the above error when a space is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable used was the problem but I'd also suggest using URLComponents instead of building the URL as string.

```
var subjectText: String = "Test Subject"

var components = URLComponents()

components.scheme = "ms-outlook"
components.host = "compose"

components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "subject", value: subjectText),
    URLQueryItem(name: "body", value: "TestingEmailNow")
]

if let url = components.url {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: I am curious to explore your answer. Will definitely give it a try now.

Comment: URLComponents is only available on iOS 10+

Comment: URLComponents is iOS 7.0+ :). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents

Comment: thats really weird, i'm looking at the in app documentation from swift playgrounds and it says SDKs
iOS 10.0+
macOS 10.12+
tvOS 10.0+
watchOS 3.0+
Unknown SDK 8.0+

Comment: Since my App is targeting iOS 10+, therefore I have accepted this answer. @Pochi answered first and solved my problem as well, so I am upvoting it. Thank you, both for your support.

Answer (score 3):

You made a simple mistake.

check your line

```
var stringURL: String = "ms-outlook://compose?subject=" + subjectText + "&body=TestingEmailNow"
```

you are using **subjectText** instead of **encodedSubject**

Complete code:

```
var subjectText: String = "Test Subject"

var encodedSubject = subjectText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

if let encodedSubject = encodedSubject {

    var stringURL: String = "ms-outlook://compose?subject=" + encodedSubject + "&body=TestingEmailNow"

    // Convert the string to a URL.
    var url = URL(string: stringURL)

    if let url = url {
        // Open the app that responds to the URL scheme (should be Outlook).
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem!, Since you are now using swift, I suggest you try out these kind of simple code snippets using "playgrounds". Bugs like this become really easy to find there.

Comment: I have just edited your answer by "Unwrapping" the encodedSubject in the final URL.

Comment: You don't need to unwrapp encodedSubject, thats what the "if let encodedSubject = encodedSubject" does. if let is used to check for nil and at the same unwrap it to be used inside the if's scope. You could use a guard as well with the same effect.

Comment: Without unwrapping, Build Fails.

Comment: Do you have a: "if let encodedSubject = encodedSubject { rest of code }" ?

Comment: Got it. My bad.